# IFTResult to cvMat pixel coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect-sdk

first of all sorry for my English 
I´m using Microsoft's Kinect SDK with the face tracking API, and I´m getting the face rect with `GetFaceRect` function. What I want to do now is to convert the video Buffer to an OpenCV `Mat` and then remove everything but the face with OpenCV.
To convert from video frame to OpenCV mat I use this:

```
cv::Mat * openCVImg = new cv::Mat(cameraConfig.Height, cameraConfig.Width, CV_8UC4);
memcpy(openCVImg->data, m_KinectSensor.GetVideoBuffer()->GetBuffer(), m_KinectSensor.GetVideoBuffer()->GetBufferSize());
```

The problem is when I try to draw the face rect again, but this time with the OpenCV `Mat` i got the rectangle displaced to the left and is not matching with my face.

I read that the image may come with a stride but with:

```
m_KinectSensor.GetVideoBuffer()->GetStride() / m_KinectSensor.GetVideoBuffer()->GetBytesPerPixel()
```

I got almost 640 wich is the width of the frame

Comment: This is the original image with the right rect https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxktzxultniqrgi/orig_image.png And the result image https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public_share/result_image.png?w=bfc9d6a7

Comment: result image isn't showing.

Comment: Oops, I´m really sorry.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8cjhoal3eiqgr8/result_image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! As Esteban previously suggested, instead of using  `memcpy` y copy byte per byte from      `IFTResult` to `cv::Mat`

Comment: I suggested it but deleted my comment because I was not sure if it was the problem^^